# Listing of user instance roles in Grails App using Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a list of all users in my Grails app and I want to see users roles on this list. How can I get this? My app uses Spring Security plugin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default domains User and Role you should be able to se who's who by doing for example `UserRole.list()`.

But the name of the domain-class may differ if your domain for users isn't called User and the same thing goes for your roles.